# Projection operator not supported. (CosmosDB -> MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm executing the follow query in CosmosDB (using Driver of MongoDB).

```
db.sendies.find({
'actions':
{
    $elemMatch:
    {
        'done': false,
        'date':
        {
            $gte: ISODate('2018-12-01 00:00:00 000Z')
        }
    }
}},{
'actions':
{
    $elemMatch:
    {
        'done': false
    }
}})
```

The error.

```
Error: error: {
"_t" : "OKMongoResponse",
"ok" : 0,
"code" : 2,
"errmsg" : "Projection operator not supported.",
"$err" : "Projection operator not supported."
}
```

The filter it's work, but the projection don't be working..
When i execute in MongoDB local, the projection working too.

Comment: This is because CosmosDB does not run MongoDB under the hood. They provide a "MongoDB-like-compatibility", but not all MongoDB operators are supported, and be warned that the same query in MongoDB and CosmosDB could return different result.

Comment: It's true.. I'm trying organize results looking in documentation. [mongodb-feature-support](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support)

Comment: It's supported to some extent now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support-36